# What's a more formal way of saying "a bit of a stretch"

Tags: phrase-request

Say you've just read an online discussion post and want to comment on the fact that the writer has jumped from point A to point B without attempting to convince of the validity of the connection. What could you write on that would be more refined than "that's a bit of a stretch"? I should mention that I don't have continued interest in understanding their reasoning and am looking for no more than another way to say "that's a bit of a stretch."

Comment: "Please show your reasoning for this assertion."

Comment: **That's a big leap.**

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Ah, I've chosen a poor example. I want a phrase that can be uttered when one doesn't actually care to understand the reasoning behind the assertion.

Comment: I'd format it as a question: `You didn't explain the connection between A and B very well; care to explain your reasoning?` or `Jumping from A to B is a big leap of logic; care to explain your reasoning?`

Comment: **Could you show the steps you used to arrive at your conclusion?** / **How did you arrive at that conclusion?**

Comment: @CookieMonster I like "That's a big leap." Searching it on Google doesn't return that many hits relevant to the meaning I seek, however. Is this a common phrase?

Comment: `A big leap` is relatively common, as phrases go. In my humble opinion, it's not too informal to use here.

Comment: -1. You seem to want to have your cake and eat it too:  *a more formal way .... does not necessitate further interaction ....I don't have continued interest in understanding their reasoning...*

Comment: What exactly do you want to say?

Comment: @CookieMonster Just a more respectable way of saying "that's a bit of a stretch." I believe you have already given me what I wanted with "that's a big leap."

Comment: You could say that 'B is a dangling assertion; it's not clear how it follows from A'.

Comment: You could also say, "that doesn't really follow."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell me if this fits your requirements:

> Wow. That's quite a leap.

Answer (score 0):

**I might format it like a question:**

> Jumping from A to B is a big leap of logic; care to explain your reasoning?
>
> You didn't explain the connection between A and B very well; care to explain your reasoning?

The latter fragment, <kbd>care to explain your reasoning?</kbd> could be omitted at your discretion.

---

However,

> The logical jump between A and B is a bit of a stretch...

Would be perfectly reasonable -- It's not too informal.
Optionally, if <kbd>bit of</kbd> feels too informal,

> The logical jump between A and B is quite a stretch...

---

Formatting it as a question like this isn't necessarily the only way to do it, though. Use your discretion.

Comment: I agree with you – I think "bit of a stretch" is more figurative than informal. (One could use "quite a stretch" if "bit of" seems too informal.)